# OOP advice for messaging objects design

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, architecture

My scenario is like this:

I have a messaging system when you dispatch a message to different destinations by the message type.

that's my current design:

```
Abstract class: MessageKindAbs

MessageKind1 extends MessageKindAbs  
MessageKind2 extends MessageKindAbs
MessageKind3 extends MessageKindAbs
```

and so on..

Now `MessageKind3` is a special kind. it's purpose is to send the content of `MessageKind1` or `MessageKind2` to log process.

So I created inside `MessageKind3` a list of `MessageKind3Items`:

```
list<MessageKind3Item> MessageKind3ItemList...
```

`MessageKind3Item` includes the information of `MessageKind1`/`MessageKind2` for logging purposes.

so basically what happens is that each `MessageKind3Item` also includes `MessageKindAbs` type.

but that makes no sense for me.

For example: send a message to DB queue and log the information that `MessageKind1` holds and `MessageKind2` holds.

So my OOP design got a bit complicated.

Anyone could help me find my way over here?

I could have created inside `MessageKind3Item` another instance type of `MessageKindAbs` but I am not sure it make sense.

thanks,
ray,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could have created inside MessageKind3Item another instance type of
>   MessageKindAbs but I am not sure it make sense.

You can not, it's abstract.

---

Since MessageKind3 is for logging so its structure is known.
Thus for MessageKind3 items create a special LogItem class that will be instantiated with something like:

```
LogItem createLogItem(MessageKind1) {  return new LogItem(); }
LogItem createLogItem(MessageKind2) {  return new LogItem(); }
```

And attach these items to MessageKind3.

You are trying to tightly couple all your classes with inheritance and this were the problem lies.

Comment: I mean reference type not instance. 2. I am trying to use OOP in order to minimize tightly coupled.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. My suggestion is about putting in a logging items rather then instances of different classes - this will reduce components coupling and their knowledge about each other.

Comment: MessageKind3 suppose to do more things thens just logging. logging of MessageKind1/MessageKind2 was just one example. it could for example send those messages to an email service.. I am just giving an example. the thing is that each MessageKind object supposed to be addressed to different destination while MessageKind3 holds the information of MessageKind1 and MessageKind2

Comment: I think I get you now:) so If I got more stuff to do like Monitoring I Should also create new list of MonitorItems?

Comment: Do you think I should create some abstract Item having all "operational-items inheritance from it? (LogItem extends ItemAbs, MonitoringItem extends ItemAbs...)

Comment: Yes, if log items differ significantly they could form a parallel hierarchy but it's not necessary be a complete duplicate of the MessageKind hierarchy.

Comment: Vitaly, If I would tell ya that MessageKind3 is not only for logging but it can do more stuff.. let's say for monitoring? Mybe I should change my whole design that for each new "command" ill create seprate MessageKind? tell me your thoughts. thanks.

Comment: Do you mean sending many messages rather than one with all information about logging/monitoring/etc? Yes, it makes sense to separate responsiblities (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), e.g. logging and monitoring can be on separate servers.

Comment: I mean my system got a messageKind1 messageKind2 and Messagekind3 - which could contain the information of messageKind1 and messagekind2 for different purpose. That's was my prob. How to design it in a better way.

Comment: My previous message is also relevant if you receive large message. When you receive the large message you can divide into several small messages and put them into the corresponding destinations (logging, monitoring, etc) for further processing. Will it help?

Answer (score 3):

Let all messages that can be sent to the log process implement an interface. For example:

```
public interface Logable {

    void logTo(PrintWriter write);
}
```

Than `MessageKind3` only needs to maintain a list of `Logable`. Note that using `PrintWriter` is just a suggestion. You may need a more elaborate type of parameter there to make logging easier in the interface implementation.

MessageKind3 will then look like this:

```
public class MessageKind3 extends MessageKindAbs {

    private List<Logable> logables;

    //...

    public List<Logable> getLogables() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(logables);
    }
}
```

And the `logables` will contain instances of `MessageKind1` or `MessageKind2` since they implement `Logable`.

Comment: so how MessageKind3  will include inside of it the information of MessageKind1 and MessageKind2 ?

Comment: So if I have more operations like "email-ables" or "monitor-ables" i will just duplicate all lists?

Comment: @rayman I think your suggestion is heading a bit in the wrong the direction, because then you would aggregate multiple responsibilities in `MessageKind3`. Maybe for such a case you should have a look at the adapter pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: I like that answer. But one more clarifying. why Do I need the logTo? I mean as soon as the message got to its destination, it's already known where it should logo. "Make logging easier in the interface implementation." - could you please elaborate ? thanks!